# Login form not working for simple blog

Tags: php, hash, login-script

So i followed a tutorial here: http://daveismyname.com/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php-bp#.U3zILN6wXMM to create a simple blog, and everything seems to be working except the login form. I have 2 users saved in my database, but neither of them work when I try to login with them.  I got it to work yesterday, but I think restarting my computer has deleted the password hash that it uses to verify the information, but I'm not really sure.

PHP (Login Form):

```
     <<?php
//include config
require_once('../includes/config.php');


//check if already logged in
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); } 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Admin Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="login">



    <?php
    //process login form if submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if($user->login($username,$password)){ 

            //logged in return to index page
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;


        } else {
            $message = '<p class="error">Wrong username or password</p>';
        }

    }//end if submit

    if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <p><label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value=""  /></p>
    <p><label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password" value=""  /></p>
    <p><label></label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  /></p>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if this is needed, but here is the config file

PHP(config File):

```
    <?php
         ob_start();
         session_start();

         //DB connection info
         define('DBHOST','127.0.0.1');
         define('DBUSER','root');
         define('DBPASS','ledyard');
         define('DBNAME','blog');

         $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

         //Timezone
         date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');


         //Load classes
         function __autoload($class) {
            $class = strtolower($class);
              //If call adjusts path
            $classpath = 'classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
            if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
                require_once $classpath;
            }

            $classpath = '../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
            if(file_exists($classpath)) {
              require_once $classpath;
            }

            //If call adjusts admin path
            $classpath = '../../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
            if(file_exists($classpath)) {
              require_once $classpath;
            }


         }

         $user = new User($db);
    ?>
```

Here is the class.user.php file which defines the login function.

PHP(USERS file):

```
<?php 

    class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function create_hash($value)
    {
        return $hash = crypt($value, '$2a$12#'.substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(sha1(microtime(true), true))), 0, 22));
    }

    private function verify_hash($password,$hash)
    {
        return $hash == crypt($password, $hash);
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT password FROM blog_members WHERE username = :username');
                $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
                $row = $stmt->fetch();
                return $row['password'];

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="error">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){
        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        if($this->verify_hash($password,$hashed) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: where is the login function defined?

Comment: I think the function you are talking that was deleted after restart is the whole login function. there is no login script in you files.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the login script.

Comment: May be you are missing classes/class.user.php file

Comment: Nope, its definitely in there.  Though let me clarify, the script works, my password doesn't. I will receive the <p class="error">Wrong username or password</p> Message.

Comment: Sidenote: `session_start();` needs to be inside all files, if it's not already, and doesn't seem to be in `USERS file`

Comment: I did not know that.  I'm assuming it should be at the top of all files?

Comment: It must reside inside all files and at the top; yes. Include it and try it again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `session_start()` only needs to be called once, not put at the top of every file. It's in his config file, which will be run on every page.

Comment: @Styphon You may have a point there. Yet, things get kinda tricky when using classes.

Comment: Yeah, I added it to class.users.php, but its in config.php, so its called in all other files that include that, which is all of them save class.user.php

Comment: Just make sure that you're not including `session_start();` twice. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if that will help also. Use `var_dump()` to track what's set or not. And/or `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened replacing `$pdo` with your PDO connection variable.

Comment: Yeah, I actually got an error when including it in class.users.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just copying/pasting you code then copy again you script and then try.. if works then compare codes wht was the problem.

Comment: Nope, I've been over the code multiple times, and I have tried that already. I'm pretty sure the error resides with password hashing somewhere, but Its an area I'm not all to familiar with.

Comment: Seems this problem is with other users too.. read comments down there on the link you provided.

if not found comment there you problem i'm sure the owner can help you better

Comment: Yeah, i did some of the suggestions in the comments yesterday, and they worked fine, but it was obviously not a permanent solution.  I'll have to research passwords/hashing and logins more.

Comment: Okay, the problem existed elsewhere.  I was adding the actual password to my database instead of adding the hashed password, and that is why none of my log-ins worked, I found it after carefully looking over the new user form.  Thanks.